# Is it possible to get an svg string from Flutter Path object?

Tags: svg, flutter, path

Is there any ideas how to get an svg element from Path object (not on Flutter Web)?
For example, having `new Path()..LineTo(10, 30)`, we could convert it into an svg "d" attribute `d="L 10,30 z"`?
Maybe there is a plugin to do same conversion?

Comment: My post about this hasn't gotten much traction either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971904/flutter-dart-svg-path-to-string.  What I had to end up doing was create a method getSVGString. In that method I take the same logic that builds my Path object and just manually build a string in the same fashion. A little tricky but it looks like that's all we have for now.

Comment: @mac, i've written a proxy wrapper for `Path`. That's all