# Flutter/Dart SVG Path To String

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I am creating a drawing application in Flutter/Dart. I build the canvas by keeping track of the placeable objects and using a CustomPainter for each object to draw its path. Now I want to export the canvas. To do this I am "serializing" it and saving it to a file. Part of this is creating an svg tag as part of my custom file. This svg tag will be an svg file in and of itself that is comprised of the path strings of each object. My issue is this: I've found a million ways to convert a string into a Path object, but I cannot find the reverse. Each of my objects has a Path property. How do I get the path string from those objects? Or do I have to build them manually?

```
class DrawingObject {
  Path path;

  void formPath(){
     path = Path();
     path.moveTo(10, 10);
     path.lineTo(20, 20);
  }

  String getPathString(){
     //How do I get this?
  }
}
```

The example above is an over simplification, but how would I get the svg path string from "path" in the "DrawingObject" above?

Comment: do something like this: `class MyPath extends Path {` and override every `moveTo` / `lineTo` etc methods so that they store their params somewhere and it could be used for generating the final `String` (or instead of storing the params just append `String` corresponding to each drawing command to some final `String` path representation)

Comment: So there is no baked in way to do this that I'm missing? It is a manual implementation then?